# How to call salt-ssh (SSHClient) via Python API

Tags: python, salt-stack

I installed Salt in a Python 3 virtual environment and created a Salt configuration that uses a non-root folder for everything (`/home/user/saltenv`). When using the `salt-ssh` command inside the venv, e.g. `salt-ssh '*' test.ping`, everything works as exptected. (Please note that the config dir is resolved via a `Saltfile`, so the `-c` option is omitted, but that should not matter.)

When calling the `SSHClient` directly via Python however, I get no results. I already figured out that the roster file is not read, obviously resulting in an empty target list. I am stuck somehow and the [documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/clients/) is not that helpful.

Here is the code:

```
import salt.config
from salt.client.ssh.client import SSHClient

def main():
    c_path = '/home/user/saltenv/etc/salt/master'
    master_opts = salt.config.client_config(c_path)

    c = SSHClient(c_path=c_path, mopts=master_opts)
    res = c.cmd(tgt='*', fun='test.ping')
    print(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it seems, the processing of some options differs between the CLI and the Client. `salt-ssh` does not use the `SSHClient`. Instead, the class `salt.client.ssh.SSH` is used directly.

While `salt-ssh` adds the `config_dir` from the `Saltfile` to the `opts` dictionary to resolve the `master` config file, the `SSHClient` reads the config file passed to the constructor directly and `config_dir` is not added to the options (resulting in the roster file not being found).

**My solution is to include `config_dir` in the `master` config file as well.** The code from the question will then be working unchanged.

*Alternative 1:* If you only have one Salt configuration, it is also possible to set the environment variable `SALT_CONFIG_DIR`.

*Alternative 2:* The `mopts` argument of `SSHClient` can be used to pass a custom configuration directory, but it requires more lines of code:

```
config = '/home/user/saltenv/etc/salt/master'
defaults = dict(salt.config.DEFAULT_MASTER_OPTS)
defaults['config_dir'] = os.path.dirname(config)
master_opts = salt.config.client_config(config, defaults=defaults)
c = SSHClient(mopts=master_opts)
```